# Override default title tag set in head section by putting another for better SEO

Tags: html, asp.net, seo, page-title

Is it good to override default title tags in following scenario?

- I am using nested master pages on my website (ASP.Net).
- By default the titles in head section (that appear in the address bar) are set to default title -- say mywebsite.com - {active page name}.
- On a certain page, I want to display some more important information in title (for better SEO results) -- say mywebsite.com - {page title} - {some more important information}

Your opinion with expertise is highly appreciated.

Comment: That is the right aproach, thats how it is being done

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Comment: I did add seo and page-title tags to it for more relevance. @BilltheLizard May I know how is it off-topic?

Comment: You're asking for opinions, not for help in getting a program to work. SEO questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd agree with your approach with one caveat - the most important stuff should come first in the title, not last.  So it would be more like:

```
{some more important information} - {page title} - mywebsite.com
```

See how stack overflow does titles as a good example.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for putting your opinion. I will try overriding it.

Comment: Overriding did not work, I may need to try something different. The first title tag gets the priority, which I can't do for the nested master page I am working on (base master page already contains first title tag).

Answer (score 1):

Yes but in terms of SEO and usability the meta title should have the format:

Page Name | Website Name

The page name should contain all relevant key words / key phrases. Don't tack extra stuff onto the end or beginning - be consistent across all pages because it will seem more professional.

And the meta title shouldn't exceed 100 characters in total (less is better but not always practical).

This format is search engine optimised, looks good in search results and is more useful in the browser if the user has several tabs open at the same time.

Comment: +1, But don't totally agree with the 100 chars parts. Sounds like _something to do to make Google happy_ line, but I agree you shouldn't write a sentence for a `<title>`.

Comment: By {some important information}, my point was examplary, but it is good to know what makes google happy (100 characters). I care about SEO only, as well I dont wanna do something bad.

Comment: @Chris Cannon : I tried overriding title by putting 2 title tags, but that didn't work. *The information in first <title> tag gets the priority*. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Thanks @RyanB Yes it is something to make Google happy but isn't most of SEO the same? Google has over 50% of market share worldwide I believe. Actually what I should of said is any characters past the 70 mark are likely to be cut in Google search results.

Comment: @DPatel is this an error you are getting? You might be doing something wrong. There should only be 1 title tag on a page. You can easily override a title tag set on the master in a child page.

Comment: @Chris: Somebody edited the original question. I had mentioned that I am trying to do this on a nested master page (using ASP.Net). Since I had no direct way to get control over master page's title in head section, I was assuming to put another title tag in child master page. But, I figured out that **the first title tag gets the priority**. So, found a workaround to access title from server side on child master page and modify it in **Pre-render** part to effectively handle it.

Comment: @DPatel yes that is the way that I was going to suggest.